# How do I save a file using python's httplib2?

Tags: python, httplib2

I can run the following code:

```
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http('.cache')

response, content = h.request('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CXFfl9luHPM/TV-Os6opQfI/AAAAAAAAA2E/oCgrgvWqzrY/s1600/cow.jpg')

print(response.status)

with open('cow.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

When I run the code, I download a file called cow.jpg which is what I want, but I also get a duplicate image with a different name called: 2.bp.blogspot.com,-CXFfl9luHPM,TV-Os6opQfI,AAAAAAAAA2E,oCgrgvWqzrY,s1600,cow.jpg,77ba31012a25509bfdc78bea4e1bfdd1. It's the http address with commas plus other junk. Any ideas on how I can create only one image using httplib2?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just write the content to a file:

```
with open('cow.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Comment: Thanks, zeekay.  I knew it was something blindingly obvious that someone who knew Python would get.

Comment: I add your lines above and download a file called cow.jpg, but I also get a duplicate image with a different name called: 2.bp.blogspot.com,-CXFfl9luHPM,TV-Os6opQfI,AAAAAAAAA2E,oCgrgvWqzrY,s1600,cow.jpg,77ba31012a25509bfdc78bea4e1bfdd1.  It's the http address with commas plus other junk.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I do not know what you are doing, so it's hard to say. Update your question with an example of what you are trying now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and method urlretrieve, the second argument is the file location.

**for python 2.x**

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(URL, path_destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using urllib2 ok for you, too? If yes, you can use this function:

```
def download_file(url):
    """Create an urllib2 request and return the request plus some useful info"""
    name = filename_from_url(url)
    r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
    info = r.info()
    if 'Content-Disposition' in info:
        # If the response has Content-Disposition, we take filename from it
        name = info['Content-Disposition'].split('filename=')[1]
        if name[0] == '"' or name[0] == "'":
            name = name[1:-1]
    elif r.geturl() != url:
        # if we were redirected, take the filename from the final url
        name = filename_from_url(r.geturl())
    content_type = None
    if 'Content-Type' in info:
        content_type = info['Content-Type'].split(';')[0]
    # Try to guess missing info
    if not name and not content_type:
        name = 'unknown'
    elif not name:
        name = 'unknown' + mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type) or ''
    elif not content_type:
        content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]
    return r, name, content_type
```

#### Usage:

```
fp, filename, content_type = download_file('http://url/to/some/file')
with open('somefile', 'w') as dst:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fp, dst)
```

This code has the advantage that is never reads the whole file into memory - so it works fine for huge files, too. Besides that, it also gives you the filename received from the server and the content-type in case you want/need it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure the safeguards you put in the code will come in handy soon.